# What is EOF and what is its significance? How can it be noticed?

Tags: c, eof, getchar

While studying `getchar()` function in C ,I came across this `EOF` being returned , I want to know how can its existence be noticed, where is it stored?

Can we type `EOF` character explicitly?

Comment: Can we type EOF character explicitly?

Answer (score 3):

`EOF` is short for **End of File**. It's not an actual character, but more like a *signal* that indicates the end of input stream.

Think about `getchar()`, it's used to get a character from `stdin` (the standard input). How could it tell when the `stdin` stream has come to the end? There must be a special return value which is different from any valid characters. `EOF` plays this role.

To generate `EOF` for `stdin`, type <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> on Unix systems, or <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> on Windows.

Comment: When we give input by keyboard , does enter also works like EOF?

Answer (score 1):

`EOF` is the named constant to apply for End Of File when reading from a *stdio* input stream.  If you look at the `getchar()` prototype, you'll first notice some strange thing is that it returns not a `char` value, but an `int`.  Normally, `EOF` translates in some negative integer value (historically `-1`) meaning it's impossible to generate that character from the keyboard/input file.

Definitely, `EOF` constant **is not** a character, is the `int` value **getchar(3)** returns on end of file condition.  This is also the reason of **getchar(3)** returning an `int` instead of a `char` value.  It is also the reason always `EOF` maps to a negative value.

**getchar(3)** returns one of 257 possible values, `0` up to `255` **and EOF** (which is normally `-1`).  Viewed as integer values, `-1` is not the same as `255`.  It's one of the oldest implemented functions in C (it's there since the first edition of "The C programming language" by K&R)

Answer (score 0):

EOF is the abbr. for End-Of-File. It's the special character for indicating that you have reached the end of the file you're reading a file stream.

Normally, people check whether they have reached to the end of file by:

```
while(!feof(fileStream)) {
    // read one line here or so
    ...
    // do your stuff here.
    ...
}
```

Comment: `EOF` is not a character. It's a signal. Also most uses of `feof()` like in your answer are probably wrong.